# How to import Excel data in pandas as list?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, list, explode

My Excel worksheet has some columns, one of which is Python list-like column. If I import this Excel data using pandas.read_excel, is it possible for pandas to recognize that column as list at this stage or later? I am asking because I have comma-seperated values residing in Excel and I want to use pandas' explode() after importing the Excel file.

I tried to wrap the Excel cells with [""] but the importing and exploding did not work as desired. Any guidance?

Thanks!

[image: Excel snapshot]

```
data = {
  "Name": ["A", "B", "C","D"],
  "Product Sold": [["Apple", "Banana"], ["Apple", "Pear"], ["Pear"], ["Berry"]],
  "Prices": [[5,6], [5,8], [4], [3]]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.explode(['Product Sold', 'Prices'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
  "Name": "Apple,Pear",
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data,index=[1])
for c in pdf.columns:
    if df[c].str.contains(','):
        df[c] = df[c].apply(lambda x : str(x).split(','))
    
print(type(df.Name.iloc[0]))
```

Read in your excel file, then pass it through the for loop above and it should make lists out of comma-delimited cells.

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks! It helped. 

As the for loop applied the rule to ALL columns, I had to split the dataframe into two - one for the columns I was as list and the other for non-list. Then applied the for loop that you suggested.
I then exploded the columns and used pd.merge to join both dataframes.

Thanks again

Comment: ```
df = pd.read_excel(path, sheet_name="Sheet1", header=1) 
df1 = df['Name']
df2= df[['Product_Sold', 'Prices']]


for c in df2.columns:
    df2[c] = df2[c].apply(lambda x : str(x).split(','))
    
df2 = df2. explode(['Product_Sold', 'Prices'])
merged = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index = True, right_index = True, how='right')

```

Comment: Nice! I updated the answer to include handling non-list columns. Cheers!